# pty man page doubt/question

Tags: c, linux, freebsd, ioctl, pty

`man pty` says...

```
   The  BSD ioctl(2) operations TIOCSTOP, TIOCSTART, TIOCUCNTL, and TIOCREMOTE
   have not been implemented under Linux.
```

why so? How is these operations taken care of in `linux`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BSD-style PTYs [have been deprecated since Linux 2.6.4](http://linux.die.net/man/7/pty). System V (UNIX 98)-style PTYs should be used instead.

That's probably the reason why these `ioctl` operations remain unimplemented to this day.

Comment: I've a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460035/pty-terminal-packet-mode-tiocpkt