# pty terminal packet mode TIOCPKT

Tags: c, linux, unix, terminal, pty

If I start a terminal, how do I know what mode it starts in? Who decides that? Can I start my terminal in packet mode i.e. [TIOCPKT](http://www.unix.com/man-page/Linux/4/tty_ioctl/)

I came across this [Packet mode](http://osr600doc.sco.com/en/SDK_sysprog/_Packet_Mode.html) link which says: `Packet mode is enabled by pushing the pckt module on the master-side.` - I do not understand this exactly.

Comment: Posted a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614618/linux-equivalent-of-i-push

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link you refer to is for SCO Unix, which has the [STREAMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STREAMS) I/O subsystem. There is a pretty good overview of STREAMS [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19455-01/805-7478/index.html) (its for Solaris, but same concepts apply to other *nixes).

The manual page tells you that you have to push the pckt module onto the stream, which is done with an ioctl() call with the [I_PUSH](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19620-01/805-3179/6j31igpbj/index.html) command. The first link above should make this concept clearer, as it describes how STREAMS works.

But alas, Linux does not support STREAMS. To enable packet mode of a pty on linux, you call ioctl() with TIOCPKT as in the first link of yours.

The default when you create a new pty is normal (non packet) mode.

Comment: Thanks @nos. Appreciate your response. I am a little confused now. How is stream mode and packet mode related? Are they opposite of each other? what is pckt module that you are referring to?

Comment: The pckt module is the name of the software piece(as the documentation you pointed to in the question says) implements packet mode over pty's on Unixes that uses STREAMS. Unless you are using Solaris, AIX or SCO Unix, this is nothing you need to be concerned about. pty packet mode means your pty master is able to receive certain control information from the slave, and it means each read() call on the pty will have a different structure than if you do not enable packet mode: the 1 byte will tell you whether this is control information, or whether it is normal data.

Comment: Note that it's quite unclear what you mean by "start a terminal" in your question. If you simply start a terminal emulator application, you do not need to concern yourself about this as you'll only interact with the slave side. If you are creating and controlling a pseudo terminal(pty), you decide yourself what you want.

Comment: Thanks @nos. By "Start a terminal" I mean, I start a shell. So when I start a shell on `linux`, it will never be in `packet mode`?

Comment: @hari a shell is hooked up to the slave part of a pty/tty, which can never be in packet mode.

Comment: I thought I would be on master side and underlying hardware would be on slave side, no? If I Am on slave part then who is master in that case? (thanks for continuous help).