# Linux equivalent of I_PUSH

Tags: c, linux, ioctl

This question is related to [pty terminal packet mode TIOCPKT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460035/pty-terminal-packet-mode-tiocpkt)

What the `linux` way of enabling `packet mode`? I could not find `I_PUSH` working when passed in `ioctl` function.

Comment: This q was here some days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460035/pty-terminal-packet-mode-tiocpkt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TIOCPKT` is exactly what you want, according to the [`tty_ioctl(4)` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/4/tty_ioctl): the argument is a pointer to an integer which is non-zero to enable packet mode, or zero to disable it.

Comment: Thanks for responding. What does it mean by "pointer to a non-zero integer" ? And how do I call it: `ioctl(fd, TIOCPKT,....??)`

Comment: `int flag = 1; ioctl(fd, TIOCPKT, &flag);`

Comment: I am getting error - `Inappropriate ioctl for device`. I am on `Linux 2.6.32-26-generic`.

Comment: It should work on the master side of a pty.  It will give that error otherwise.